# How long can the French Toast last?

Tags: toasting

I often make French toast. Sometimes I have to make myself several servings ahead of time. I was wondering how long I can keep French toast?

Comment: If you are asking how long it will be safe to eat then this is a duplicate of a question that's been answered a long way back. Are you asking how long it will keep it's 'toastiness'?

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate of the food safety question, because I suppose the asker already knows how long the toast keeps its texture. But if it was really meant to be about the texture, independently of food safety, Nickolas can edit his question to make that clear, and flag it for reopening.

Comment: 0 days, reheated French toast is garbage food.